# How to use components in QML

Tags: windows, qt, qml

I'm trying to use components to avoid repetition of code, on my attempt below i did not get any error, and the children's are being found, however, the particles are not visible.

I wonder what the proper way to reference the `ImageParticle` and `Emitter` that are children of the `Item` inside the component.

Using Qt 6.5, Windows

---

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Particles 2.0
        
Rectangle {
        id: root
        color: "transparent"
    
        ParticleSystem {
            id: x
        }
        ParticleSystem {
            id: y
        }
     
        Component {
            id: custom
    
            Item {
    
                ImageParticle {
                    source: 'qrc:/files/particles/assets/particle.png'
                    color: '#ff4208'
                    colorVariation: 0.2
                    rotation: 10
                    rotationVariation: 20
                    rotationVelocity: 20
                    rotationVelocityVariation: 20
                    entryEffect: ImageParticle.Scale
                    opacity: 1
                }
    
                Emitter {
                    property string _id: ""
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    width: parent.width
                    height: parent.height
    
                    velocity: AngleDirection {
                        angle: 270
                        angleVariation: 180
                        magnitude: 12
                        magnitudeVariation: 20
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        function createEmitter(properties) {
            var obj = custom.createObject(root);
    
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
    
                var children = obj.children[i];
                if (children instanceof ImageParticle) {
                    children.system = properties.system;
                    continue;
                }
                if (children instanceof Emitter) {
                    children._id               = properties.id;
                    children.system            = properties.system;
                    children.emitRate          = properties.emitRate;
                    children.lifeSpan          = properties.lifeSpan;
                    children.lifeSpanVariation = properties.lifeSpanVariation;
                    children.size              = properties.size;
                    children.maximumEmitted    = properties.maximumEmitted;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    
        Component.onCompleted: {
    
            createEmitter({ 
                'id'               : 'emitter1',
                'system'           : x, 
                'emitRate'         : 40, 
                'lifeSpan'         : 4000, 
                'lifeSpanVariation': 8000, 
                'size'             : 52, 
                'maximumEmitted'   : 20 });
    
            createEmitter({ 
                'id'               : 'emitter2',
                'system'           : y, 
                'emitRate'         : 50, 
                'lifeSpan'         : 5000, 
                'lifeSpanVariation': 9000, 
                'size'             : 62, 
                'maximumEmitted'   : 30 });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points:

- Please do not use `x`, `y` as property ids. These will clash with root window's coordinates
- Instead of createObject(), consider using `Repeater` `model` for a declarative creation/destruction of your dynamic objects
- The `ImageParticle` and `Emitter` properties must all be set declaratively, attempting to populate the properties imperatively after the objects were created does not work

Here's a working example of the above:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Particles
Page {
    title: "Particle Emitter Example"
    ParticleSystem { id: sys1 }
    ParticleSystem { id: sys2 }
    Component {
        id: custom
        Item {
            anchors.fill: parent
            ImageParticle {
                anchors.fill: parent
                system: modelData.system
                source: modelData.imageSource
                color: '#ff4208'
                colorVariation: 0.2
                rotation: 10
                rotationVariation: 20
                rotationVelocity: 20
                rotationVelocityVariation: 20
                entryEffect: ImageParticle.Scale
                opacity: 1
            }
            Emitter {
                anchors.fill: parent
                system: modelData.system
                emitRate : modelData.emitRate
                lifeSpan: modelData.lifeSpan
                lifeSpanVariation: modelData.lifeSpanVariation
                size: modelData.size
                maximumEmitted: modelData.maximumEmitted
                velocity: AngleDirection {
                    angle: 270
                    angleVariation: 180
                    magnitude: 12
                    magnitudeVariation: 20
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Repeater {
        model: [{
                'system'           : sys1, 
                'emitRate'         : 40, 
                'lifeSpan'         : 4000, 
                'lifeSpanVariation': 8000, 
                'size'             : 52, 
                'maximumEmitted'   : 20,
                'imageSource'      : "reddot.svg"
            },{
                'system'           : sys2, 
                'emitRate'         : 50, 
                'lifeSpan'         : 5000, 
                'lifeSpanVariation': 9000, 
                'size'             : 62, 
                'maximumEmitted'   : 30,
                'imageSource'      : "greendot.svg"
        }]
        delegate: custom
    }       
}

// reddot.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<circle cx="16" cy="16" r="8" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="red" />
</svg>

// greendot.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<circle cx="16" cy="16" r="8" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Excluding the x/y thing whats wrong with the code i provided?

Comment: It seems much of the Emitter properties are immutable, in other words, you can only set the properties at construction time. Your code, you construct a blank Emitter and, by this time, it will not react to subsequent property changes, so you're stuck with a non functioning Emitter because it was non functional at construction time.

Comment: I see, thank you, Stephen! I have created a **new** question about how to use QML plugins with a **static** Qt build, if you have any experience in this topic could you please take a look at it?

Comment: `x` and `y` do not have special meaning in QML.

Comment: @GrecKo I meant to avoid clashing with https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-item.html#x-prop

Comment: There's any way to dynamically create the `ParticleSystems` i tried creating it from inside the component but i get an error when trying to set a value to its `id` property https://pastebin.com/SRv9j1yU